# Unable to use Debezium postgres(11) with rds

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, amazon-rds, debezium, aws-msk

Unable to setup Debezium Postgres connector using MSK connect on RDS

Trying to set up Postgres Connector with Debezium with Postgres on RDS. The highest previledge granted by AWS is `postgres` user having `rds_superuser` role, which doesnot have REPLICATION permission

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Roles.html

Cannot get `rdsadmin` password from AWS as its protected.
Cannot create `REPLICATION` roles from postgres user.

```
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
publication.autocreate.mode=all_tables
database.user=postgres
database.dbname=postgres
topic.creation.default.partitions=1
database.server.id=123456
tasks.max=1
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=b-1.**
database.history.kafka.topic=umg-kafka-postgres-history
publication.name=umg-publication
database.port=5432
plugin.name=pgoutput
topic.creation.enabled=true
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
topic.prefix=pre-prod-rds
database.hostname=**
database.password=**
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
topic.creation.default.replication.factor=2
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

Getting the following error on MSK connect

```
[Worker-07e12fb7b8fe79792] [2023-06-13 14:55:22,802] WARN [pre-prod-14|task-0] Unable to use pg_replication_slot_advance() function. The Postgres server is likely on an old RDS version or privileges are not correctly set (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection:376)
[Worker-07e12fb7b8fe79792] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: must be superuser or replication role to use replication slots
```

How can i proceed ahead?